# After Xcode6-Beta3 update, cannot access keyboard information using Swift

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift, nsnotifications

Before the xcode6-beta3 update I was able to access the frame (CGRect) of the keyboard via keyboard notifications.  Now however every value I try to obtain is "nil"

notification code

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

`keyboardWillAppear` Function code

```
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){
    var keyboardSize = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.frame.size.height
    println(keyboardSize)
}
```

Any value I have tried to print has been nil:

```
tried: .frame
       .size.height
       .size
```

Any pointers (pointers, haha) or help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code adjusted like this:

```
func shrinkTextView (ncMessage: NSNotification) {

 var keyboardSize: AnyObject? = ncMessage.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]
 println("\(keyboardSize?)")

 }
```

... Prints

Optional(NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 216}})

Are you adding the observer correctly? I tried like this:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
 self, selector: "shrinkTextView:",
 name: "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification", object: nil)
```

Comment: ah, it appears i missed my defaultCenter() call...that may be important, ill confirm this tomorrow and hit that it was answered, thanks for the reply